# Running Vue with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js, frontend, maven-frontend-plugin

Is it possible to run Vue on the Spring Boot app using `maven-frontend-plugin`?

There is an official guide on spring.io about doing this with React - you have to use the plugin's `webpack` goal to generate `bundle.js` and then just include it in your page (in my case Thymeleaf is the template engine).

I did the same with Vue but nothing seems to happen on page load. If this is not possible, what is the most simple way to use Vue frontend with Spring Boot backend?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found this solution which seems like it is the only usable one: https://escuela-tech.medium.com/deploy-vuejs-application-in-tomcat-b0010c2f8395
Basically, you just build deployable js and css with `npm run-script build` and then attach it to your page.